# Probability of winning game with $n$-point lead

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

We play a game in which I win a point with probability $p$ and you win a point with probability $1-p$. The first player to have an $n$-point lead wins the game. How likely am I to win the game?

For $n=2$, one can observe that the cases that allow me to win are:

- Me winning immediately, with probability $p^2$.
- A 1-1 tie followed by me winning, with probability $2p(1-p)\cdot p^2$.
- A 1-1 tie, then a 2-2 tie, then me winning, with probability $\left(2p(1-p)\right)^2\cdot p^2$.
- etc.,

so the total probability of me winning is $$P = p^2\cdot\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(2p(1-p)\right)^k=\frac{p^2}{1-2p(1-p)} = \frac{p^2}{2p^2-2p+1}.$$

But what happens if a higher lead is required? Then I can't argue anymore that there must be a sequence of ties.

Comment: this is a rephrasing of the usual [Gambler's Ruin Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin)

Comment: @lulu That looks about right, thanks! This would be unfair coin flipping with $n_1=n_2=n$, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $\quad$

Comment: Your $n=2$ result can be written as $\frac{p^2}{p^2+(1-p)^2}$ and the more general $n$ question as $\frac{p^n}{p^n+(1-p)^n}$ with a neat combinatorial argument (the match will almost surely finish, and intermediate points where I win some and you win the same number can be ignored)

Answer (score 1):

Let $w_{i}$ the probability that the first player win the game starting from an advantage over the second player of $i$, for $i\in\{-n,-n+1,\ldots ,0,\ldots n-1,n\}$ (if $i$ is negative then it can be seen as a disadvantage), then we have the linear recursion

$$
w_i=p\cdot w_{i-1}+(1-p)\cdot w_{i+1},\quad w_{-n}=0,\, w_n=1
$$

Now you just need to solve it to find the general solution.